# Google Big Query schema inference is incorrect

Tags: google-bigquery

When pushing in data in csv format as given below:

> G000021318,   17.0,   New,    0.0,    None,   jan,    2010

Big query removes the G00000 and converts the field to an Integer.

Code to create the table as follows:

```
List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();
    sources.add("gs://" + googleBucket + "/" + accountId + "/" + sourceFile + "_" + account.getSuffix() + "/part*");
    loadConfig.setSourceUris(sources);
    TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
    tableRef.setDatasetId(datasetId);
    tableRef.setTableId(flagVolumeMonthTable + "_" + account.getSuffix());
    tableRef.setProjectId(googleProjectId);
    loadConfig.setDestinationTable(tableRef);
    loadConfig.setFieldDelimiter(",");
    loadConfig.setAutodetect(true);
```

Am I missing something or it is a bug in the Big query schema detection?

Comment: Interestingly, it won't even load the data in for me. I get the error: _"There are no column descriptions provided for table"_. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: This looks like a bug with autodetect - probably better to file it in issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: @GrahamPolley The code is fine. It reads the table but the type inference is incorrect. In fact it is weird because it removes characters from the first column which are not integer (letter G in the example csv) and also the redundant 0's left after removing G. It means it trying to convert the whole thing into integer actively instead of giving a type exception or something.

Comment: Yeah, as @MoshaPasumansky has already said, it looks like a bug.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky Issue created https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=921&thanks=921&ts=1485068853

Comment: in the meantime, don't use auto-detection (declare that column a string)

Answer (score 4):

The problem happened because BigQuery's autodetect code detected that `G000021318` is ISO compliant format for the [Haitian gourde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haitian_gourde) currency due to `G` prefix, and eagerly proceeded to interpret data as `INT64` representing `21318` gourdes :)
We have fixed autodetect code to only react for unambiguous currency symbols such as $, €, £, ¥, ¢ etc. 
P.S. The fix will propagate into production systems within weeks.

Comment: Wow!! I hope my country's currency symbol (₹) is recognised. We bypassed the issue by specifying the types. Had to write a whole set of backend admin feature just to specify the types. Makes the data pull more robust and less error prone.